# How can I change test suite name for Botium test using botium bindings. Currenlty it is coming default name

Tags: automation, chatbot

I am using botium bindings with mocha test runner and mochawesome reporter. I want to change default test suite name coming in mochaawesome report.

I have tried by modifying botium.spec file by below commna
 -didnt work

I have tried to set up test suitename in envs in botium.json file. didnt work

1) botium.spec.js

```
 const bb = require('botium-bindings')
    bb.helper.mocha().setupMochaTestSuite('Demo Test suite')
```

2) botium.json

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "Test chatbot",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "watson",
      "WATSON_APIKEY" : "xxx",
      "WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID": "xxx",
      "WATSON_URL" : "https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api",
      "WATSON_COPY_WORKSPACE" : true
    },
    "Sources": {},
    "Envs": {
      "BOTIUM_TESTSUITENAME" : "Demo Test suite"
    }
  }
}
```

3) package.json

```
{
  "name": "Botium_Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options \"code=false,reportTitle=Digital CityCool,inline=true,overwrite=false\"  --exit spec",
    "mocha": "mocha spec"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "botium-bindings": "^2.0.10",
    "botium-connector-echo": "latest",
    "botium-connector-watson": "0.0.5",
    "mocha": "latest",
    "mochawesome": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "botium": {
    "convodirs": [
      "spec\\convo"
    ],
    "expandConvos": true,
    "expandUtterancesToConvos": false
  }
}
```

mocha report test suite name coming as 'Botium Test Suite for Botium_Test'
 I want test suite name as defined in botium.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trial #1 was pretty close. Use this in the botium.spec.js:

```
const bb = require('botium-bindings')
bb.helper.mocha().setupMochaTestSuite({ name: 'Demo Test suite' })
```

Comment: Can I use botium.json file to update the test suite name?

Comment: No, but I agree, would be a nice thing - added it to our Botium backlog.

Comment: Is part of tomorrow build - botium.json PROJECTNAME is the preferred test suite name from now on